# Vuetify component v-text-field is not getting class

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to add class to v-text-field in vuetify, but when it is rendering to the dom, I realized that the input does not have the class.

```
   <v-text-field label="Login" class="upper" name="login" prepend-icon="person" type="text" v-model="usuario"></v-text-field>
```

I got this:

```html
<div class="v-input upper v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted">
<div class="v-input__prepend-outer">
<div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">person</i>
</div>
</div>
<div class="v-input__control">
<div class="v-input__slot">
<div class="v-text-field__slot">
<label for="input-10" class="v-label v-label--active theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Login</label><input name="login" id="input-10" type="text"></div></div><div class="v-text-field__details">
<div class="v-messages theme--light">
<div class="v-messages__wrapper">
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

I want the upper class in the input field.

Comment: please provide the CSS class rules

Comment: .upper{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: Didi you try with <v-text-field :class="upper" :value="value">

Comment: Your code is working for me. Here you have a working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SilliconMachine/mrx041oL/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS code is applied on `<div class="v-input upper v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted">` but needs to be applied to `<input name="login" id="input-10" type="text">`

Change your CSS code to:

```
.upper input { 
text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Comment: Esto me sirvio bastante bien. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me, but it applies only to the placeholder. If you want to apply it to the input text you need to do the following:

```
.upper input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here you have a working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SilliconMachine/mrx041oL/3/